# Unit Test ajax failure with Q-Unit

Tags: jquery, ajax, unit-testing, qunit

I'm using jQuery $.when to handle ajax callbacks, and I'm using [mockjax](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/) to simulate various responses in my unit tests. One of the responses returns a status error of 500. My failure callback throws an error, and in Q-Unit I'm trying to catch that error using "raises" but all I'm getting is the actual error.

Here is the code:

```
var bar = new Object();  
// ajax call, returns a promise object 
bar.ajaxCall = function () {  
  return $.ajax({
      url: "foo/foo"
      , dataType: "json"
      , data: { "blah": "blee" }    
  }); 
}

// function I'm testing ...
bar.handleAjax = function () {
    return $.when(ajaxCall.call(this))
      .done(function(data) { /* Success callback */ })
      .fail( throw "Error!!"; });
}
```

Unit test:

```
// Mock ajax call in the unit test
var mock = $.mockjax({
   url: "foo/foo"
   , contentType: "json"
   , status: 500
});

// unit test for "load"
loadTest = function () {
   test("testing load failure", function () {
      stop(); // stop the test so QUnit knows to wait for the ajax response
      raises(function () {
         var promise = bar.handleAjax();
      }, "We expect an error to be thrown");
      setTimeout(function() { 
         start();
      }, 500);
   });
}
```

How can I rewrite the test to be sure that handleAjax is throwing an error at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that calling `handleAjax()` inside `raises()` will return immediately and the error will be thrown outside this function.

To solve this you can make the ajax call synchronous and this way the erro will be thrown inside `raises()`.

```
raises(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
  bar.handleAjax();
}, "We expect an error to be thrown");
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/uvupid/3/edit#javascript,live)** is the working code.

Your problem is that you are throwing a error inside `fail()` and you cannot easily control when this fail callback will be called and exception will be thrown unless you execute it synchronously. You can rewrote your code that instead of throwing an error you will call a callback.

```
bar.handleAjax = function(success, error) {
  return $.when(this.ajaxCall.call(this))
    .done(function() { success && success.call(this); })
    .fail(function() { error && error.call(this); });
};
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/uvupid/6/edit#javascript,live)** is the example.

Looking forward to better ideas :).

Comment: Thanks a lot @dzejkej. Is there any reason not to have all ajax run synchronously in unit tests? It seems like it would be easier to write tests since you wouldn't have to set timeouts whenever you had to wait for operations to occur. Though this also wouldn't help you detect race conditions.

The second solution works for me, I think it's cleaner to throw the error that way.

Comment: @stinkycheeseman: I don't have problem with running ajax synchronously in tests as it is making things a lot more simple to implement. But some people are automatically getting angry when they see a combination of `async: false` and `$.ajax` :P. I don't see any other solution without changing `bar` implementation.